# Adding an action to an existing controller (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I am new to Ruby on Rails, I have completed the [Blog Tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started_with_rails.html).

I am now trying to add an additional action to the controller, called 'start'.

```
def start
end
```

I have added a view page "app/views/posts/start.html.erb" containing nothing but simple html.

When I go to /posts/start i get the following error.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#show 
Couldn't find Post with ID=start
```

I understand the error, the show action is being executed and start is not a valid ID. Why doesn't the start action get executed, is there some part of the MVC architecture or configuration I am missing ?

Below is my posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /posts/start
  def start
  end

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.xml
  def index
    @posts = Post.find(:all)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.xml
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
    end
  end

end
```

Yes I have restarted the server and tried it with Mongrel and webrick.

Comment: Please retag..."on" should not be a tag

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your routing isn't set up to allow that route. Assuming you're using the default scaffolding, put this line *before* the `map.resources :posts` line in config/routes.rb:

```
map.connect "posts/:action", :controller => 'posts', :action => /[a-z]+/i
```

The regex for `:action` restricts it to just a-z (to avoid catching things like /posts/1). It can be improved if you need underscores or numbers in your new actions.

Answer (score 45):

The error you're making is actually a pretty common one.

Basically, Rails automatically maps URLs for your scaffolds.  So when you created the Posts scaffolds, Rails is mapping the URL routes for it.  One such route is the URL for viewing a single post:  /posts/(post_id)

So, when you're entering the URL /posts/start Rails thinks you're saying "Hey, give me the post with ID = start.  So Rails complains that the show method can't find a post with such ID.

One quick way to fix this is to make sure your config/routes.rb has the route for the start action before the scaffolding routes:

```
# Route for start action
map.connect '/posts/start', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'start'
# Default mapping of routes for the scaffold
map.resources :posts
```

Anyway, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll have to read up more on routes.

Comment: I think one of the things that help most when trying to understand how routes work in RoR is to remember that they get evaluated top to bottom.  So it is generally a best practice to have your more specific routes before the general (catch-all) routes.

Comment: I used match '/pages/action', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'action' and it worked.

Answer (score 33):

On Rails 4.x use:

```
get '/posts/start', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'start'
```

On Rails 3.x use:

```
match '/posts/start', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'start'
```

instead of

```
map.connect '/posts/start', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'start'
```

it solved my issue.

Answer (score 9):

Try this if you are using rails 3.0.3

in your route.rb

```
 resource :posts do
   collection do
     get 'start'
   end
 end
```

this might help

Answer (score 2):

I want to say, sometimes Rails gets sticky with routes-caching, even in the **development** environment.

It may help to **restart your Rails server**.  This has worked for me more times than I can count when receiving this error.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
map.resource :post, :collection => { :my_action => :get}
```

Comment: In Rails 3, the collection option adds `"collection"=>{"my_action"=>:get}` to the GET params.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem, in the routes.rb file where

```
map.resource :post
```

I added with collection argument, so it stayed this way:

```
map.resource :post, :collection => { :my_action => :get}
```

Comment: In Rails 3, this adds `"collection"=>{"my_action"=>:get}` to the GET params.