# Edit multiple records, controller & routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, railscasts

I am following railscast 198 http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually, trying to update it to rails 3, and am stuck with a routing error.  The route http://localhost:3000/orders/edit_individual gives me the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in OrdersController#show - Couldn't find Order with ID=edit_individual
```

I have updated and used his rails 2 routing

```
map.resources :products, :collection => { :edit_individual => :post, :update_individual => :put }
```

to the rails 3 convention as described by engineyard http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/ (updated to my needs)

```
  resources :orders do
    collection do
      post :edit_individual
      put :update_individual
    end
  end
```

Here's what I've tried:

I've tried changing the routes resources as suggested by the answer to: [Adding an action to an existing controller (Ruby on Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401241/adding-an-action-to-an-existing-controller-ruby-on-rails/401340#401340) but the same error still shows.  I've tried removing the cancan load and authorize resources, the 'resources :orders' route entry, as well as the 'show' entry in the controller, but another error indicates it's still trying to show a record with ID='edit_individual' instead of treating "edit_individual" like a route.

Here are my routes and controller,

```
myapp::Application.routes.draw do

      resources :products

      resources :roles

      devise_for :users #, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

    #  match 'dashboard' => 'user_dashboard#index', :as => 'user_root'

      resources :orders do
        collection do
          post :edit_individual
          put :update_individual
        end
      end

      resources :orders   


class OrdersController < ApplicationController
    load_and_authorize_resource # cancan method

      def index
      end

      def show
      end

      def edit_individual #from railscast 198
        @orders = current_user.customer_orders
      end

      def update_individual
        @orders = Order.update(params[:orders].keys, params[:orders].values).reject { |p| p.errors.empty? }
        if @orders.empty?
          flash[:notice] = "Orders updated"
          redirect_to orders_url
        else
          render :action => "edit_individual"
        end
      end # ...etc.
```

I've removed the cancan methods, but is it the culprit still?  I've tried everything I can think of and am at a dead end.. any ideas?

edit:

the output from command prompt:

```
Started GET "/orders/edit_individual" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Jun 30 11:19:02 -0700
 2011
  Processing by OrdersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"edit_individual"}
  ←[1m←[36mOrder Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "or
ders"."id" = 0 LIMIT 1←[0m
Completed   in 2584ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Order with ID=edit_individual):
```

and the route in my html:

```
    <%= link_to 'Update Payments Received', edit_individual_orders_path %>
```

and rake routes:

```
edit_individual_orders POST   /orders/edit_individual(.:format)         {:action=>"edit_individual", :controller=>"orders"}
 update_individual_orders PUT    /orders/update_individual(.:format)       {:action=>"update_individual", :controller=>"orders"}
                   orders GET    /orders(.:format)                         {:action=>"index", :controller=>"orders"}
                          POST   /orders(.:format)                         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"orders"}
                new_order GET    /orders/new(.:format)                     {:action=>"new", :controller=>"orders"}
               edit_order GET    /orders/:id/edit(.:format)                {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"orders"}
                    order GET    /orders/:id(.:format)                     {:action=>"show", :controller=>"orders"}
                          PUT    /orders/:id(.:format)                     {:action=>"update", :controller=>"orders"}
                          DELETE /orders/:id(.:format)                     {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"orders"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably run "rake routes" and see what route it gives for "edit_individual" action.

Also your log

```
Started GET "/orders/edit_individual" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Jun 30 11:19:02 -0700
```

says that you are calling a post action as get.

Try below

```
  resources :orders do
    collection do
      get :edit_individual
      put :update_individual
    end
  end
```

OR either way you can use

```
<%= link_to 'Update Payments Received', edit_individual_orders_path, :method => "post" %>
```

Comment: Spot on. you have to make your form post...and don't forget the uber secret magical _method hidden input that the rails form helpers insert...this will override what you THINK you're setting on the form's method property

Answer (score 0):

So the error message: OrdersController#show - Couldn't find Order with ID=edit_individual tells me that for whatever reason you're being routed to the 'show' action, which is inherently expecting something like

```
/orders/1
```

meaning it's a member not a collection. Are you certain that the url being hit in your server output matches /orders/edit_individual?

Comment: I'm not certain.. I make some pretty dumb mistakes sometimes.  See the edit in my post for the command prompt output and the route I used.