# Couldn't find Sound without an ID - Stuck Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm beginner at Rails, and im actually stuck with apparently a "beginner problem".

I got a "sounds" scaffolded controller, and i had to add an action "sendit". I can't have access to the sound from my view to my controller.

This is my error when i try to access to **"http://127.0.0.1:3000/sounds/sendit.14**" (Why it's sendit.14 and not sounds/sendit/14 or sounds/14/sendit ?)

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SoundsController#sendit

Couldn't find Sound without an ID

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/sounds_controller.rb:74:in `sendit'
Request

Parameters:

{"format"=>"14"}
```

Here is my code :

**Sound Controller :**

```
def sendit
    @sound = Sound.find(params[:id]) # ----- Error is on this line -----
    # Do Job
  end
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
<% @sounds.each do |sound| %>
  <% if sound.user_id == current_user.id %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= sound.title %></td>
      <td><%= sound.user.email %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', sound %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_sound_path(sound) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', sound, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Send', sounds_sendit_path(sound) %></td>
```

**routes.rb**

```
  devise_for :users

  match "/sounds/sendit/", :controller => "sounds", :action => "sendit"

  resources :users, :sounds
```

I did this in the route file because of [Adding an action to an existing controller (Ruby on Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401241/adding-an-action-to-an-existing-controller-ruby-on-rails)

When i do **rake routes** , this is the output :

```
              [...]
           sounds_sendit        /sounds/sendit(.:format)       sounds#sendit 
                   users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
                  sounds GET    /sounds(.:format)              sounds#index
                         POST   /sounds(.:format)              sounds#create
               new_sound GET    /sounds/new(.:format)          sounds#new
              edit_sound GET    /sounds/:id/edit(.:format)     sounds#edit
                   sound GET    /sounds/:id(.:format)          sounds#show
                         PUT    /sounds/:id(.:format)          sounds#update
                         DELETE /sounds/:id(.:format)          sounds#destroy
                    root        /                              home#index
```

(I actually don't understand the first line, why there is no POST / GET, and why it's sounds_sendit and no sendit_sound like others default actions? How to fix it? )

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this :

```
match "/sounds/sendit/", :controller => "sounds", :action => "sendit"
```

Use this:

```
  resources :sounds do
    member do
      get :sendit
    end
  end
```

Then you will be able to use the `sendit_sound_path` helper to link to the action correctly:

```
link_to "link text", sendit_sound_path(sound_object)
```

Hope this does it for you,...

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you a lot. ;) 
2 days i was stuck on this problem, i promise i will read and learn all the route section on the rails doc ;)

Comment: he already did this have a look at the routes.rb posted above

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't have route to the action with id as param, so rails assumes that id is format
You have to create route for that

```
resources :sounds do
  post :sendit, on: :member
end
```

Comment: What's the difference between your code and davidb code? You just dont specify the get || post?

Comment: It is just a little bit cleaner. You could use match over post, but if don't need all types of request just stick to one type

Answer (score 1):

You should define in your routes the id parameter, see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

```
match "/sounds/:id/sendit/", :controller => "sounds", :action => "sendit"
```

You can name your route by using the 'as' option. An example from the above site:

```
match 'exit' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
```

If you only want a get, then you can use get instead of match. An example:

either:

```
match 'photos/show' => 'photos#show', :via => :get
```

or shorter:

```
get 'photos/show'
```

Comment: Got a question : if instead of "/sounds/:id/sendit/" i wroted "/sounds/:somethingelse/sendit/", it should work? or the ":id" is interpreted like that?

Comment: It will just pass a parameter called :somethingelse in the params hash. the symbol :id is nothing magical.